# How do we see the sun?

Tags: visible-light, vision

This question was originally posted almost a year ago and it was misunderstood probably because of its wording. I understand my question better now.

**Let me put the question this way now:**

If possible what characteristics of light change as it hits some object ?

For example if we see the sun because of some characteristic properties of the light that it emits,

then how do such properties change when the light hits some other object and we are able to see the object and not the sun?

**The earlier form of the question:**

We know that it is light that enables us to see objects. Non luminous objects reflect light received from luminous objects.

But how do we see luminous objects themselves, for example the sun?

I suppose it must be other luminous objects that enable us to see the sun, for example other stars. But shouldn't then we see the sun brighter sometimes and fainter sometimes because light falling on it may vary during its revolutionary course.

Comment: "But shouldn't then we see the sun brighter sometimes and fainter sometimes because light received by it may vary at different points in space."  Our orbit shouldn't very that much in terms of distance from the sun.  Are you measuring the intensity of sunlight year-round?  I get the feeling that it is brighter sometimes; just that relative to how bright it always is you can't tell that it changes.

Comment: I've edited my question cause you got it wrong @jMac

Comment: ...why can we not see luminous objects simply by the light they're emitting in your understanding?

Comment: Light comes from luminous objects - it an energy emission. When it goes directly to our eyes we see the object. Some light reaches non-luminous objects, then bounces into our eyes; form this light we principally gain information about the non-luminous object, not the source.

Comment: @ACurioisMind I already mentioned that in my question. We see objects by the light they reflect and not that which they emit.

Comment: @FaizIqbal We see the light they reflect and the light they emit.  Our eyes are designed to detect light, regardless if it is reflected or from a direct source.

Comment: Even reflection is a kind of radiation, it's "re-radiation". A photon is absorbed, an electron increases its energy level, then the electron emits a photon and drops back to the earlier energy level.

Comment: have a look at black body radiation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Black_body.svg .to see radiation from a radiating body the wavelencths have to be in the colored region where our eyes respond. all bodies radiate but only very hot bodies'  radiation is visible to our eyes. detectors measure it. The radiated light can be reflected from body to boyd, and if the reflected wavelengths are in the visible, the objects  are, in addition to the black body , illuminated .All bodies around us black body radiation  is in the infrared, so not visible, except in stars, or candles.

Comment: the moon is an illuminated celestial body reflecting the sun's ilumination including the visible band so we see it.

Comment: Your comments were helpful and easy to grasp. Maybe write a answer so that this post becomes more wholesome. Thanks. @annav

Comment: I dont understand why this post is so downvoted. people who downvote questions, should atleast say why they do so, before doing so. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All material bodies,i.e.masses made up of atoms and molecules, radiate according to the black body radiation. Black body radiation is one of the pillars for the need of quantum mechanics as classical electromagnetism could not explain the measured [black body](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html) distributions.

[image]

The plot above is for 5000K which is about [the  temperature of the sun,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_spectrum_en.svg) and one can see that the maximum of radiation is in the visible spectrum. This is also true for all stars, that is why they are sources of radiation,  not reflected radiation.

Most bodies on earth have much lower radiation, and there is no self luminosity in the visible, except for candle flames and other incandescent metals and materials. The moon gets reflected light from the sun.

When the light is reflecting coherently, it carries the information/phases  between light rays so images as in mirrors are the result.

Comment: Made the comments into an answer

Comment: Helpful. @annav I am choosing this as the answer since this is more detailed. Meanwhile StephenG's answer was also great.

Answer (score 2):

We see objects because they radiate light.  We see the Sun because it radiates light.

Your confusion seems to be that light from the Sun is being absorbed and radiated by the other objects we see.  They also radiate light.

Everything we see is radiating light.

Comment: That is convincing , but how does  radiated light contain information about the object radiating it ?

Comment: @FaizIqbal The light will radiate differently depending on the surface.  That is how we can see different objects.  Those differences are recognized by our brains as shadows and colours etc.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I understand it relatively  better now.

Comment: A mirror also absorbs and radiates light... But we see images in it and not the mirror itself....according to your explanation we see things simply because they radiate light..so what about a mirror

Comment: @FaizIqbal  a mirror is reflected radiated light, which has a metalevel of patterns in the radiation,